# How can I use my Android phone as a voice changer?

Tags: bluetooth

Trying to use Robovox Pro on my android (samsung phone) and i have a bluetooth speaker yet want use real time voice changer with my external mic under my mask (to disguise my voice) like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_k4Z9j5PEY (We do not have this in australia) HELP please

Comment: It sounds like you already have everything you need. Where's the problem? What do you need help with?

Comment: Well when i use the app it's keep's getting feedback so wondering which external mic would be useful with samsung phone ?

Comment: That's not really an Android problem. If you have problems with feedback, you need to change the physical layout of the system, to isolate the Bluetooth speaker from the mic you're using. If you need shopping advice for microphones, that's not really something we can help you with.

Comment: How do i that if i was to isolate bluetooth speaker ?

Comment: I mean isolate acoustically, i.e. with foam or by moving them further apart

Answer (score 0):

Use this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baviux.voicechanger I tested it and it's fun

Comment: I want a REAL-TIME voice changer not a recording :(